# Qt5 Project on Windows with MinGW

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, mingw-w64

I have been using Visual Studio 2012 for a Qt/C++ project.

I am trying to migrate over to MinGW so that I can use C++11 entirely instead of the partial support that MSFT's compiler offers. Using CMake to generate the project and making was proceeding very well, compiling all the subprojects and the main project itself.

However, the linking is giving me some errors and I'm not sure how to resolve them:

> Linking CXX executable Owl.exe
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x1e):
>   undefined reference to `__imp__ZN9QTreeViewC2EP7QWidget'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x7b):
>   undefined reference to`_*imp*_ZN9QTreeViewD2Ev'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x116):
>   undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK17QAbstractItemView5modelEv'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x1a1):
>   undefined reference to`
>   _*imp*_ZNK18QStandardItemModel9findItemsERK7QString6QFlagsIN2Qt9MatchFlagEEi'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x303):
>   undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8QVariantD1Ev'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x350):
>   undefined reference to`_*imp*_ZeqRK7QStringS1_'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x53e):
>   undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8QVariantD1Ev'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x649):
>   undefined reference to`
>   _*imp*_ZNK9QTreeView10indexBelowERK11QModelIndex'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x669):
>   undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK17QAbstractItemView5modelEv'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x6b1):
>   undefined reference to`
>   _*imp*_ZN17QAbstractItemView15setCurrentIndexERK11QModelIndex'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x6c1):
>   undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8QVariantD1Ev'
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj):BoardTreeView.cpp:(.text+0x6d6):
>   undefined reference to`_*imp*_ZN8QVariantD1Ev'
>   c:/progra~1/mingw-~1/x64-48~1.1-p/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   CMakeFiles\Owl.dir/objects.a(BoardTreeView.cpp.obj): bad reloc address
>   0xf in section `.text$_ZNSt9exceptionC2Ev[_ZNSt9exceptionC2Ev]'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Deltas\CMakeFiles\Owl.dir\build.make:1217: recipe for target
>   'Deltas/Owl.exe' failed mingw32-make[2]: *** [Deltas/Owl.exe] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles\Makefile2:435: recipe for target
>   'Deltas/CMakeFiles/Owl.dir/all' failed mingw32-make[1]:** 
>   [Deltas/CMakeFiles/Owl.dir/all] Error 2 Makefile:115: recipe for
>   target 'all' failed mingw32-make: ** [all] Error 2

The project compiles and links just fine using Visual Studio (and Xcode, FWIW), so I'm not sure what the linker is missing.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Advice: don't use MinGW compiler it's really really crappy. You may, yourself, benchmark and compare MinGW with Visual Studio Express (any version) which is for free, and you'll see at least a 200% performance gain on Visual Studio Express.

Comment: I spent a good portion of the day yesterday trying to get Qt5 to build with 64-bit MinGW. I eventually gave up when I saw the steps to build WebKit. I am sticking with Visual Studio and will just have to wait for MSFT to complete C++11 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download Qt for MinGW (or build it yourself, if you're using a different version of MinGW than the version the Qt release was built with.) The VS version of Qt cannot be used with MinGW.